# I am getting java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"

Tags: java, android, int

I have seen many questions regarding this but i have not been able to solve this problem. I have a form with EditTexts a user is filling that also has a calculator. When the math is done there's a value of total premium. The user then needs to click on the submit button to add the details to his cart and then he can start over with another form of the same kind or proceed to checkout. If he fills another form and clicks on the submit button again. these data are presented in a RecyclerView to which the total premium of each form should add and present itself at the bottom of the cart so that he can pay for it. 
The problem is once i click on the submit button after the math to proceed to the cart. The app crashes and gives me  'Caused by java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null".. Kindly help. I can't see where the error is. After doing the math i convert the result to a string then i add it to the cart when i click on the submit button. Then on the Cart class. The forms should add the totals of all the total premiums.

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
    at com.urbanx.urbaninsure.Cart.loadListProposals(Cart.java:167)
    at com.urbanx.urbaninsure.Cart.onCreate(Cart.java:113)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

This is part of my proposal form class where i fill in the form and submit

```
    private void fillProposalForm() {

    if (etFirstNameOfProposer.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        etFirstNameOfProposer.setError("First name cannot be empty");
    } else{
        firstNameProposer = etFirstNameOfProposer.getText().toString();
    }
        if (etSurnameProposer.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        etSurnameProposer.setError("Surname cannot be empty");
    } else {
            surnameProposer = etSurnameProposer.getText().toString();
        }
        if (etLastNameProposer.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        etLastNameProposer.setError("Last name cannot be empty");
    } else
        {
            lastNameProposer = etLastNameProposer.getText().toString();
        }
        if (etPassportNo.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        etPassportNo.setError("ID/Passport number cannot be empty");
    } else{
            idNumber = etPassportNo.getText().toString();
        } if (etPinNo.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        etPinNo.setError("KRA pin number cannot be empty");

    }else {
            pinNo = etPinNo.getText().toString();
    }if (etMobile.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        etMobile.setError("Mobile number cannot be empty");
    }else {
            mobile = etMobile.getText().toString();
    } if (etEmail.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        etEmail.setError("Email cannot be empty");


    }else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(etEmail.getText().toString()).matches()){
        etEmail.setError("Invalid email address");
    }
        else {
            email = etEmail.getText().toString();
    }if (etDrivingTime.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        etDrivingTime.setError("Driving time duration cannot be empty");

    } else {
            drivingTime = etDrivingTime.getText().toString();
    }if (etDuration.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        etDuration.setError("Duration of insurance cannot be empty");

    } else {
            duration = etDuration.getText().toString();
    }if (etVehicelReg.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        etVehicelReg.setError("Vehicle registration cannot be empty");

    } else {
            vehicleReg = etVehicelReg.getText().toString();
    }if (etEstimate.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        etEstimate.setError("The present estimated value of vehicle cannot be empty");
        bSubmit.setEnabled(false);


    } else {
            marketValue = etEstimate.getText().toString();
    }


    spTypeOfCoverage.setAdapter(TypeOfCoverageAdapter);
    spTypeOfCoverage.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             typeOfCoverage = spTypeOfCoverage.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });


    spMake.setAdapter(MakeAdapter);
    spMake.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (i == 0) {

                vehicleMake = spMake.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            } else if (i == 1) {
                spModel.setAdapter(subaruCarsAdapter);

                vehicleMake = spMake.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


            } else if (i == 2) {
                spModel.setAdapter(toyotaCarsAdapter);

                vehicleMake = spMake.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


            } else if (i == 3) {
                spModel.setAdapter(nissanCarsAdapter);

                vehicleMake = spMake.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


            } else if (i == 4) {
                spModel.setAdapter(mercedesBenzCarsAdapter);

                vehicleMake = spMake.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


            } else if (i == 5) {
                spModel.setAdapter(BMWCarsAdapter);

                vehicleMake = spMake.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


            } else if (i == 6) {
                spModel.setAdapter(audiCarsAdapter);
                vehicleMake = spMake.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            } else if (i == 7) {
                spModel.setAdapter(landRoverCarsAdapter);

                vehicleMake = spMake.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            } else if (i == 8) {
                spModel.setAdapter(hondaCarsAdapter);

                vehicleMake = spMake.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            } else if (i == 9) {
                spModel.setAdapter(mazdaCarsAdapter);

                vehicleMake = spMake.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            } else if (i == 10) {
                spModel.setAdapter(mitsubishiCarsAdapter);

                vehicleMake = spMake.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            } else if (i == 11) {
                spModel.setAdapter(peugeotCarsAdapter);

                vehicleMake = spMake.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            } else if (i == 12) {
                spModel.setAdapter(isuzuCarsAdapter);

                vehicleMake = spMake.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            } else if (i == 13) {
                spModel.setAdapter(volkswagenCarsAdapter);

                vehicleMake = spMake.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            } else {

                vehicleMake = spMake.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
    spUseOfVehicle.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            useOfVehicle= spUseOfVehicle.getSelectedItem().toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });



    spModel.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (spModel.getSelectedItem().toString().contains("Other")) {
                 vehicleModel = spModel.getSelectedItem().toString();


            } else {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    spinnerModelYear.setAdapter(yearAdapter);
    spinnerModelYear.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            yearOfManf = spinnerModelYear.getSelectedItem().toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
     if (etLimitWindscreen.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
         etLimitWindscreen.setText(String.valueOf(0));
     }

    windscreenValue = etLimitWindscreen.getText().toString();


    if (etLimitDvd.getText().toString().isEmpty()){

        etLimitDvd.setText(String.valueOf(0));

    }

    dvd = etLimitDvd.getText().toString();

    if ( etLimitRiot.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        etLimitRiot.setText(String.valueOf(0));

    }


    riot = etLimitRiot.getText().toString();


    if ( etLimitExcessProtect.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        etLimitExcessProtect.setText(String.valueOf(0));
    }
    excessProtector = etLimitExcessProtect.getText().toString();




    if (etLimitTerrorism.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        etLimitTerrorism.setText(String.valueOf(0));
    }
    terrorism = etLimitTerrorism.getText().toString();


    if (etCourtesyCar.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        etCourtesyCar.setText(String.valueOf(0));
    }
    courtesyCar = etCourtesyCar.getText().toString();


    calculateInsurance();

     proposalId = "number";


    currentProposer = new ProposalDetails(proposalId, firstNameProposer
            ,lastNameProposer,surnameProposer, idNumber, pinNo,
            email, mobile, drivingTime, duration, vehicleReg,
            marketValue, typeOfCoverage, useOfVehicle, vehicleMake, vehicleModel,
            yearOfManf, windscreenValue, dvd, riot,
            excessProtector, terrorism, courtesyCar, basicPremium, trainingLevy,
            policyHolders, stampDuty, totalPremium);
    currentProposer.setFirstNameProposer(firstNameProposer);
    currentProposer.setSurnameProposer(surnameProposer);
    currentProposer.setLastNameProposer(lastNameProposer);
    currentProposer.setEmail(email);
    currentProposer.setMobile(mobile);
    currentProposer.setDrivingTime(drivingTime);
    currentProposer.setIdNumber(idNumber);
    currentProposer.setVehicleReg(vehicleReg);
    currentProposer.setDuration(duration);
    currentProposer.setMarketValue(marketValue);
    currentProposer.setTypeOfCoverage(typeOfCoverage);
    currentProposer.setUseOfVehicle(useOfVehicle);
    currentProposer.setVehicleMake(vehicleMake);
    currentProposer.setVehicleModel(vehicleModel);
    currentProposer.setYearOfManf(yearOfManf);
    currentProposer.setWindscreenValue(windscreenValue);
    currentProposer.setDvd(dvd);
    currentProposer.setRiot(riot);
    currentProposer.setExcessProtector(excessProtector);
    currentProposer.setTerrorism(terrorism);
    currentProposer.setCourtesyCar(courtesyCar);
    currentProposer.setBasicPremium(basicPremium);
    currentProposer.setTrainingLevy(trainingLevy);
    currentProposer.setPolicyHolders(policyHolders);
    currentProposer.setStampDuty(stampDuty);
    currentProposer.setTotalPremium(totalPremium);


   // mProposalInformation.child(proposalId).setValue(currentProposer);

    new Database(getBaseContext()).addToCart(new Order(
            currentProposer.getFirstNameProposer(),
            currentProposer.getSurnameProposer(),
            currentProposer.getLastNameProposer(),
            currentProposer.getMobile(),
            currentProposer.getIdNumber(),
            currentProposer.getDuration(),
            currentProposer.getVehicleReg(),
            currentProposer.getTotalPremium()));







    startActivity(new Intent(ProposalForm1.this,Cart.class));

}



private void calculateInsurance() {
    double MarketValue,
            Duration ,
            TotalPremium;



    try {
        MarketValue = Double.valueOf(etEstimate.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        MarketValue = 0; // your default value
    }



    try {
        Duration = Double.valueOf(etDuration.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Duration = 0; // your default value
    }


    double Windscreen ;


    try {
        Windscreen = Double.valueOf(etLimitWindscreen.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Windscreen = 0; // your default value
    }

    double Riot  ;

    try {
        Riot = Double.valueOf(etLimitRiot.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Riot = 0; // your default value
    }


    double Terrorism ;
    try {
        Terrorism = Double.valueOf(etLimitTerrorism.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Terrorism = 0; // your default value
    }


    double Excessprotect ;
    try {
        Excessprotect = Double.valueOf(etLimitExcessProtect.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Excessprotect = 0; // your default value
    }



    double Dvd ;
    try {
        Dvd = Double.valueOf(etLimitDvd.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Dvd = 0; // your default value
    }


    double CourtesyCar ;

    try {
        CourtesyCar = Double.valueOf(etCourtesyCar.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        CourtesyCar = 0; // your default value
    }

    double Prata = 1;

    if (Duration ==  0){
        Prata = 1;

    }
    else if (Duration == 1){

        Prata = 0.3;
    }
    else if (Duration == 2){
        Prata = 0.4;
    }
    else if (Duration == 3){
        Prata = 0.5;
    }
    else if (Duration ==  4){
        Prata = 0.6;
    }
    else if (Duration ==  5){
        Prata = 0.7;
    }
    else if (Duration > 5){
        Prata = 1;
    }

    double Basicpremium = (MarketValue/100.0f) * coverageInt * Prata;
    etBasicPremium.setText(String.valueOf(Basicpremium));
    etBasicPremium.setText(""+Basicpremium);

    double Traininglevy = (Basicpremium/100.0f)* 0.45;
    etTrainingLevy.setText(String.valueOf(Traininglevy));
    etTrainingLevy.setText(""+Traininglevy);

    double PolicyholdersFund = (Basicpremium/100.0f) * 0.25;
    etPolicyHolders.setText(String.valueOf(PolicyholdersFund));
    etPolicyHolders.setText(""+PolicyholdersFund);

    double Stampduty = 40;

    etStampDuty.setText(String.valueOf(Stampduty));
    etStampDuty.setText(""+Stampduty);

    TotalPremium = Basicpremium + Traininglevy + PolicyholdersFund + Stampduty + Windscreen + Dvd + Riot + Terrorism + Excessprotect + CourtesyCar;

    int tp = (int) TotalPremium;
    totalPremium = String.valueOf(tp);
    etTotalPremium.setText(totalPremium);

    basicPremium = etBasicPremium.getText().toString();
    trainingLevy = etTrainingLevy.getText().toString();
    policyHolders = etPolicyHolders.getText().toString();
    stampDuty = etStampDuty.getText().toString();




}


    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.bSubimt:
            fillProposalForm();
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is the part of the Cart class that is giving me an error

```
     private void loadListProposals() {
    cart = new Database(this).getCarts();
    adapter = new CartAdapter(cart,this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    //Calculate totalPremium

    int total = 0;


    for (Order order:cart) {

     //   try
     //   {
      //      if( null != order.getTotalPremium() )
       //     {
                total += Integer.parseInt( order.getTotalPremium());

                Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");
                NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);

                txtTotalPrice.setText(fmt.format(total));

        //    }
      //  } catch (NumberFormatException ignored){

        }



    }
```

Comment: The error is at: at com.urbanx.urbaninsure.Cart.loadListProposals(Cart.java:167) could you highlight that line (167)?

Comment: I guess error is here total += Integer.parseInt( order.getTotalPremium())

Comment: why did you comment **if( null != order.getTotalPremium() )**

Comment: It could be that your database has some null entries for total_premium 'cart = new Database(this).getCarts();' so even though you are not adding any new entry with null there, it just happens to have bad old data?

Comment: i commented because i thought that would fix it but its not what i want. the value is not null and yet i am receiving the error. Kindly advice

Comment: so what should i do here Ashwinee K Jha.. I don't understand

Comment: put **System.out.println(" Order toal premium " + order.getTotalPremium());** just begin of **for loop**  and see what values are coming

Answer (score 1):

here `order.getTotalPremium()` holds "null" as String. like `String val = "null"`

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: make sure that value in order.getTotalPremium() must be parsable to Integer.